# Como redimensionar 2 DataGridView igualmente?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho um formulário com 2 `DataGridView` e ao redimensionar o formulário só consigo redimensionar 1 dos `DataGridView` para todos os lados (está com `anchor` para os 4 lados) sem que o mesmo fique sobreposto ao outro `DataGridView`.

[image: Formulário com os <code>DataGridView</code>]

Levando em consideração a imagem, caso eu coloque o `anchor` para os 4 lados nos 2 `DataGridView`, o primeiro `DataGridView` sobrepõe o segundo `DataGridView`, conforme o formulário for aumentando. Caso eu coloque o `anchor` do segundo `DataGridView` para a direita e para baixo, somente o primeiro `DataGridView` aumenta de tamanho.

**Pergunta**: Há alguma forma de redimensionar os 2 `DataGridView` para todos os lados (`anchor` nos 4 lados) sem que um sopreponha ao outro e ambos fiquem do mesmo tamanho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção seria usar o control [TableLayoutPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) com a propriedade Dock a `Fill`, tem até a opção de colocar a largura das colunas em percentagem. Cada célula apenas permite um control, use um container caso necessite mais que um control por célula. Coloque também Dock a `Fill` nos controls...

Fica aqui um exemplo com controls criados em runtime:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateControls();
    }

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        var tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            RowCount = 2,
            ColumnCount = 3
        };

        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 45F));
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 10F));
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 45F));

        tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 2;
        tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30F));
        tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());

        var label = new Label { Text = "Grupo: LLL" };

        var groupBox1 = new GroupBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        var textBox1 = new TextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        var dataGridView1 = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        // A ordem que os controlos são adicionados tem importancia
        // o que tem 'DockStyle.Fill' tem de ser o primeiro a ser adicionado
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(textBox1);

        var groupBox2 = new GroupBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        var textBox2 = new TextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        var dataGridView2 = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        groupBox2.Controls.Add(textBox2);
        groupBox2.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);
        // Em design mode, poderia ser 'Bring to Front'
        groupBox2.Controls.SetChildIndex(dataGridView2, 0);

        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(label, 0, 0);
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(groupBox1, 0, 1);
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(groupBox2, 2, 1);

        tableLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tableLayoutPanel.Padding = new Padding(20);

        this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
    }
}
```